# Visual Studio 2010 Express não reconhece direito o Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Olá, eu estou com um problema, eu costumo fazer sites em html/php e estou migrando para o ASP .NET, e eu gostaria de trabalhar com Bootstrap, porém, ele funciona quando debugo a página, mas no preview não, ou seja, não consigo arrumar o Designer, vejam nas imagens:

[image: Imagem do Visual Studio 2010 Express]

[image: Imagem do Visual Studio 2010 Express]

Comment: Não mesmo, o `preview` não acompanha o site renderizado.

Comment: eita, pensei que acompanharia, o jeito é então montar seu próprio css?

Comment: Não na verdade esse preview é só para você ter noção do que está fazendo, o que importa mesmo é o site rodando e ai sim verificar se o css corresponde o que precisa...

Comment: Então compensaria mexer com isso no final do projeto?

Comment: Eu faço a parte grafica depois eu programo! é assim que eu faço particularmente

Comment: Mas como faria isso com bootstrap no vs? Para organizar as posições é recomendavel usar as grids, mas as grids não respondem no preview

Comment: ai se vai pelo código mesmo da página e não pela parte visual, posiciona igual você fazia no PHP e seja feliz ...

Comment: kkk entendido, obrigado pela informação! :p